# Макрос удаляющий все из из верхнего регистра

Tags: ms-word, макросы

Работаю в ворде 2003, занимаюсь очисткой текстов от мусора.

1. Интересует макрос, который удаляет все из верхнего регистра (номера сносок, тире итд) по всему документу
2. То же самое, но выборочно в выделенном тексте

Comment: А просто замена (регулярное выражение -- любой символ) с указанием форматирования (верхний регистр) -- не проходит?

Comment: Какой символ надо ввести в верхнее поле автозамены?

Comment: А я помню их регулярные выражения? С ворда-какого-то появились, смотрите хелп. У меня ни ворда, ни виндов под рукой нет.

Comment: что-то не получается.